# How to append empty string to FormData

Tags: javascript, jquery, multipartform-data, form-data

I have an ajax script which sends FormData object via ajax.

The code looks like this:

```
fd = new FormData();
fd.append('title', $('.some_input').val());
// few other appends including file

jQuery.ajax({
  url: 'some_url',
  dataType: 'json',
  processData: false,
  contentType: false,
  data: fd
})
```

When `$('.some_input').val()` is not empty, it works as predicted, server gets necessary param. But in the case of input value is empty string it behaves like its missing the append. How can I put empty string to formdata in this case?

Comment: Use Form.serialize for this